# Notepad++ regexp search and replace

Tags: notepad++, regexp-replace

I have a series of 12 comma-separated digits and want to extract the first, 4th, 7th, and 10th digits. How to do this without writing it out too much ?

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
```

to

```
1, 4, 7, 10,
```

And

```
148, 79, 562, 184, 28, 487, 186, 16, 792, 200, 12, 956,
```

to

```
148, 184, 186, 200,
```

And yes there is a comma and space at the end of each line, so that the regexp `\d+,`  repeats exactly 12 times per line

I want to avoid writing `(\d+, )(\d+, ){2}` 4 times and asking it to replace with `$1 $3 $5 $7`

Comment: You could match them perhaps like `\d+(?=(?:(?:,\h*\d+){3})*(?:,\h*\d+){2},$)` https://regex101.com/r/VKcW9i/1

Comment: Or keeping the comma https://regex101.com/r/OyQ0Fr/1

Answer (score 0):

find what: `[0-9]{1,3}, [0-9]{1,3}, [0-9]{1,3}, ([0-9]{1,3}), [0-9]{1,3}, [0-9]{1,3}, [0-9]{1,3}, ([0-9]{1,3}), [0-9]{1,3}, [0-9]{1,3}, [0-9]{1,3}, ([0-9]{1,3}),`

Replace with: `\1, \2, \3,`

Answer (score 0):

You can not dynamically get the capture group numbers by repeating a capture group. You would have make the capture groups part of the pattern.

```
^(\d+, )(?:\d+, ){2}(\d+, )(?:\d+, ){2}(\d+, )(?:\d+, ){2}(\d+, )\d+, \d+, $
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/67rHqU/1)

Then replace with

```
$1$2$3$4
```

If you want to match the values, you could make use of lookarounds asserting a number of repetetive parts to the right until the end of the string.

Using `\h*` matches optional horizontal whitespace characters.

```
\d+,(?=(?:(?:\h*\d+,){3})*(?:\h*\d+,\h){2}$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wSpF36/1)